# Understanding search report

Tags: patent-applications, uk, response

Following the great advice of @George White, i went on and checked patents against the [PUBLIC PAIR](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) database, to understand the flow between the applicant and the examiner, as well as [the uk equivalent](http://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-find-publication.htm).

I stumbled upon [this](https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum/Case/PublicationNumber/GB2560881) patent, and i do not understand the officer reply.
He reports relevant patents showing lack of novelty. He also points out that the invention suggests something impossible and this should be enough for rejection afaik.

And yet, the patent has been published, not even a non-final rejection?

Comment: Your UK link isn't loading for me (service down), but the same document on Google Patents says it has been withdrawn. Perhaps it just never got to the point of being examined. https://patents.google.com/patent/GB2560881A/en?oq=GB2560881

Comment: Also the idea is pretty silly. Attach a wind turbine to an electric vehicle to recharge the battery while driving. This is close to a perpetual motion idea which violates the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: Publishing of the application is automatic and not dependent on patentability

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember is that applications get published regardless of whether they get granted or don’t get granted.

Your link didn't work for me but I did go to https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-find-publication.htm and entered GB2560881 to find the particulars. If you go there you'll find a link to "Letter - Search" where the examiner points out that the idea is "contrary to well established physical laws" along with a few other issues. The Case Details page indicates the application was terminated before grant. I'm assuming it was withdrawn by the applicant based on the contents of the search letter which, to me, indicated the application would not get granted.

Answer (score 1):

The document you link to says the status is "Terminated before grant".

> Ipsum - Online Patent Information and Document Inspection Service
> New Search View on Espacenet

- GB2560881 - Renewable energy wind funnel for powering of automotive
  vehicles

  - Case Details
  - Application Number GB1704048.6
  - Application Source Form 1 Publication
  - Number GB2560881
  - Status Terminated before grant

*Terminated before grant* sounds bad to me. It is essentially an application for a perpetual motion machine. When I was practicing I had a potential client with the same impossible idea. This inventor was represented. If a professional took money and encouraged this inventor I see that as horrible.

Comment: Amazingly one of the cited patents was an issued US patent for essentially the same idea. https://patents.google.com/patent/US3444946A/

Comment: Of my two potential clients with perpetual motion devices, one was exactly this.

Comment: So not only impossible, it lacked novelty too!

Comment: One wonders whether the examiner for US3444946A ever got made fun of by his colleagues?